# MySQL get distinct values and count how many of each?

Tags: mysql

There is a status column. I need to pull all the distinct values for each one, and a number indicating how many times each unique value is in the table.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT status, count(*) as c FROM table GROUP By status;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you are after.

When you pull distinct values, there is (by definition) one of each unique value.

Can you rephrase what you are trying to do?

**UPDATE**

After reading another solution, I think I see what you are after.

Using **SELECT COUNT(*)** as given in the solution by Rufinus should do the trick.